# Vue router allways redirecting to error page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

i am trying to setup a redirect when the user is not logged in. But when i do it like in my example the URL changes but i get `This page could not be found` from nuxt. The code is inside an login.js inside the plugins folder. Then i included this in the nuxt config like this.

```
plugins: [
    '~/plugins/login.js'
],
```

And here is the actual code for handling redirecting

```
export default ({ app, store }) => {
  app.router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const loggedIn = store.state.account.loggedInAccount
    if (!loggedIn) {
      if (to.path !== '/redirect') {
        next({ path: '/redirect' })
      } else {
        next()
      }
    } else {
      next()
    }
  })
}
```

It looks like the routes are not mounted yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use `middleware`. It is the conventional way to implement the `beforeEach` function as mentioned by the official docs. You can read about it from [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/#middleware). If have access to the `route` object, `store` object and `redirect` function inside the middleware, so use `redirect` to direct to the other routes after validation.